# Prepending Text To Every Line Within Capture Group

Tags: notepad++, regex, find-and-replace, linebreaks, capture-group

What I have:

```
X
(
1
2
3
)
BREAK

Y
(
4
5
)
BREAK

Z
(
6
7
8
9
)
BREAK
```

What I'd like:

```
X,1
X,2
X,3

Y,4
Y,5

Z,6
Z,7
Z,8
Z,9
```

I'd prefer to figure out how to do this using RegEx in Notepad++.
As I understand it, I'd need something like this in the Find text box:

```
^(.*?)\((.*?)\).*?BREAK
```

with `Search Mode` being `Regular Expression` and `. matches newline` selected.

But I don't know what to enter in the Replace section of the Find/Replace input box.

How can I specify that I want to replace every instance of `\r\n` between the two brackets with the previously captured character (`X`, `Y` or `Z`)?

Comment: I'm afraid this can't be done within Notepad++ with regex, you have to write a script in your favorite scripting language.

Comment: Question: Are `X`, `Y`, `Z` single letters or do they represent something more complex (i.e. a string)? Are `1`, `2`, `3` only digits  or do they represent something more complex? How many (the max) lines may exist between parenthesis? Could you edit your question and add real test cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I assume yours `X`, `Y`, `Z` are words and `1`, `2`, `3` are numbers. If it is not the case, replace below `\w+` with any character class you need, and `\d+` with any character class you need.**

---

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^(\w+)\R\(\R(\d+\R)(?:(\d+\R))?(?:(\d+\R))?(?:(\d+\R))?(?:(\d+\R))?\)\RBREAK`
- Replace with: `$1,$2(?3$1,$3)(?4$1,$4)(?5$1,$5)(?6$1,$6)`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^               # beginning of line
(\w+)           # group 1, 1 or more word character, you can use the character class you need
\R              # any kind of linebreak
\(              # an opening parenthesis
\R              # any kind of linebreak
(               # start group 2
  \d+           # 1 or more digits, you can use the character class you need
  \R            # any kind of linebreak
)               # end group 2
(?:             # non capture group
    (\d+\R)     # group 3, same pattern as group 2
)?              # end non capture group, optional
(?:(\d+\R))?    # same as above, group 4
(?:(\d+\R))?    # same as above, group 5
(?:(\d+\R))?    # same as above, group 6
            You can add more structures as above depending on max number of lines you have.
\)              # closing parenthesis
\R              # any kind of linebreak
BREAK           # literally
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1,$2           # content of group 1, comma, content of group 2
(?3             # if group 3 exists then:
    $1,$3         # content of group 1, comma, content of group 3
)               # endif
(?4$1,$4)       # same as above for group 4
(?5$1,$5)       # same as above for group 5
(?6$1,$6)       # same as above for group 6
            Add as many similar structures as above depending on max number of lines you have.
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: First of all: thank you! This is fantastic and the `?n` is going to be very useful in the future. To answer your question, however, it's a `CREATE TABLE` statement from SQL Server. I wanted to simplify the question to just understand the topic and then adapt the code, myself. As I understand it, though, your technique uses repeated (potential) captures. Can it be done without hard-coding the maximum number of groups?

Comment: @AJS: You're welcome, glad it helps.